# Why isn't my Rails worker executing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, worker

I'm using Rails 5.0.1 on mac OS X.  I just installed redis via homebrew, and have this in my Gemfile

```
gem 'sidekiq'
```

and I have this file, app/workers/run_crawlers_worker.rb, ...

```
class MyWorker

  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform()
    puts "about to fire up service ..."
    svc = MyService.new
    svc.do_tasks
    puts "done invoking call"
  end

end
```

At a place in my web application, I have

```
    MyWorker.perform_async()
```

although I'm confident the above is getting called, I don't see any of my "perform" method in my worker called (I don't see any of hte puts output and I don't see the results of the "do_tasks" method getting executed in my db).  Is there something additioanl I need to configure to get my method invoked?

Comment: Do you have sidekiq process running?

Comment: I only have redis and Rails running.  I wasn't aware of an additional process that needed to be started.  At least, this guy doesn't mention it -- https://ryanboland.com/blog/writing-your-first-background-worker/

Comment: bundle exec sidekiq. It is also mentioned in the link you shared.

Comment: @Dave: he _does_ mention it.

Comment: Is there any way to get "bundle exec sidekiq" to automatically run when I fire up my Rails server?

Comment: Hey "bundle exec sidekiq" actually starts my background process.  That's not what I want.  I want to start the process when I launch the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You likely don't have sidekiq running, I would recommend looking into [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) which can be configured to run all of your expected processes (Rails server, workers, Redis, etc.) at once.

Comment: Because links break over time, please include all the configurations necessary to launch Foreman in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something additioanl I need to configure to get my method invoked?

You need sidekiq process running in background which will be responsible to run the jobs you enqueue.

> Is there any way to get "bundle exec sidekiq" to automatically run when I fire up my Rails server?

Put into foreman. It is pretty easy. I am assuming basic configuration, this is all you need to do

1. Install `foreman` gem. (put into bundle and do bundle install)
2. you have to create file named `Procfile` in rails root.
3. Assuming basic configuration, this is what `Procfile` suppose to contain

   ```
   web: bundle exec rails server
   worker: bundle exec sidekiq
   ```
4. then to execute both command spontaneously, just execute `foreman start`

Comment: I'm using Unicorn and Nginx .  How does that affect the configuraiton you posted above (i.e. I assume I'm not using a Procfile)

Comment: then just start `sidekiq` process, simply run `sidekiq -d`

Comment: Yeah but if I want sidekiq to start automatically when I restart my server, how do I do taht?  You say use formman.  So will adding "gem foreman" to my Gemfile be all I need to do?

Comment: You're referring to running "sidekiq -d" to run it as a daemon, but I don't want to have to run two commands when I restart my server, the first being the one to start up my unicorn daemon and my second being to run "sidekiq -d".  I would prefer that the second automatically happen when I do the first.

Comment: use foreman if u want to run these 2 things via single command, that is the standard way to do. Otherwise, you have to moneypatch the command which you use to run/restart server

Comment: Yeah but then won't I have to set up something on my system in /etc/init.d to automatically start foreman?  And then does that mean I am disabling the script /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp that starts unicorn and sets some environment variables?

Comment: No, it does not. Foreman isn't a process, it wraps other processes. When you start Rails on your server right now, you are likely doing something such as `bundle exec rails server`. With the foreman gem installed, you would replace that with `bundle exec foreman start` and the processes inside of the Procfile would start as if you started them individually. (Foreman is incredibly common in Rails apps, so much so I wish it was part of the default stack.)